# SQL Merge rows with same ID

Tags: sql, group-by

So I have a SQL query that returns a set of results like:

```
ID     Data1      Data2      Data3      Data4
1,     Null,      Null,      Null,      SomeValue
1,     Null,      Null,      SomeValue, Null
1,     Null,      SomeValue, Null,      Null
1,     SomeValue, Null,      Null,      Null
2,     Null,      Null,      Null,      SomeValue
2,     Null,      Null,      SomeValue, Null
2,     Null,      SomeValue, Null,      Null
2,     SomeValue, Null,      Null,      Null
```

And what I need to do is merge all with the same ID and make 2 rows of complete data like so:

```
ID       Data1           Data2           Data3           Data4
1,     SomeValue,      SomeValue,      SomeValue,      SomeValue
2,     SomeValue,      SomeValue,      SomeValue,      SomeValue
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

I tried using GROUP BY but it doesn't permit the rest of the values that I have in the select query.

Full SQL statement:

```
SELECT      
DISTINCT(D.DocumentNumber) AS [PTW No], 
D.ListCustomField1 AS [Work Order], 
D.ListAssetNumber AS [KKS No],
D.ListWorkToBeDone AS [Description],
D.CurrentStatusName AS [PTW Status],
D.TypeName AS [Section],
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('AreaPicklist', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString) AS [Area],
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('IssueDate', MDP.Value, D.ID) AS [Actual Start Date], 
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('CloseDate', MDP.Value, D.ID) AS [Actual Finished Date], 
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('Duration', MDP.Value, D.ID) AS [Duration], 
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('Impact', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString) AS [Potential Non-Availability],
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DerationWater', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString) AS [Deration - Water],
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DerationPower', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString) AS [Deration - Power],
dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DeclarationNumber', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString) AS [Availability Decl No/ Rev No]

FROM dbo.Document AS D LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.DocumentControlValues AS DCV ON D.ID = DCV.DocumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.MapperDocumentProperty AS MDP ON DCV.ControlId = MDP.DocumentControlMapperId
WHERE D.Stereotype = '1' 
AND CAST(MDP.Name AS nvarchar(max)) = 'FriendlyName'
AND CAST(MDP.Value AS nvarchar(max)) IN ('AreaP1_Picklist', 'ImpactAvailabilityP3_TextBlock',         'DerationWaterP1_TextBox', 'DerationPowerP1_TextBox', 'DerationDeclarationNoP1_TextBox')
```

Help welcome!

Cheers,
Dave.

Comment: what happens if 2 values in Data1 for id 1 ? if that can't happen, the structure of your table is it correct ?

Comment: (perhaps this is a bit of a hack) If all of your non-grouping columns have one value per group, try `MAX(Data1) AS Data1, ...` and add your `GROUP BY` clause back in.

Comment: @amdev, this will never happen due to the structure of the query, each row returns its own piece of data. Now I need to join them all together

Comment: @programmer43229 I don't quite understand what you mean by this, if I have 10 columns in my select clause, I believe I need to have 10 in the group by, but in reality I only want to group by the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. This is what I was trying to suggest:

```
SELECT  (D.DocumentNumber) AS [PTW No], 
        MAX(D.ListCustomField1) AS [Work Order], 
        MAX(D.ListAssetNumber) AS [KKS No],
        MAX(D.ListWorkToBeDone) AS [Description],
        MAX(D.CurrentStatusName) AS [PTW Status],
        MAX(D.TypeName) AS [Section],
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('AreaPicklist', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString)) AS [Area],
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('IssueDate', MDP.Value, D.ID)) AS [Actual Start Date], 
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('CloseDate', MDP.Value, D.ID)) AS [Actual Finished Date], 
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('Duration', MDP.Value, D.ID)) AS [Duration], 
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('Impact', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString)) AS [Potential Non-Availability],
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DerationWater', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString)) AS [Deration - Water],
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DerationPower', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString)) AS [Deration - Power],
        MAX(dbo.Sem_fn_PTWReport_ProcessData('DeclarationNumber', MDP.Value, DCV.ValueString)) AS [Availability Decl No/ Rev No]
FROM    dbo.Document AS D LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.DocumentControlValues AS DCV ON D.ID = DCV.DocumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.MapperDocumentProperty AS MDP ON DCV.ControlId = MDP.DocumentControlMapperId
WHERE   D.Stereotype = '1' 
        AND CAST(MDP.Name AS nvarchar(max)) = 'FriendlyName'
        AND CAST(MDP.Value AS nvarchar(max)) IN 
        (
            'AreaP1_Picklist',
            'ImpactAvailabilityP3_TextBlock',
            'DerationWaterP1_TextBox',
            'DerationPowerP1_TextBox',
            'DerationDeclarationNoP1_TextBox'
        )
GROUP BY (D.DocumentNumber)
```

Comment: I feel dirty for accepting this as a solution, but... thanks :) It's only a short term solution until we develop code to pull the information from the DB! Cheers, Dave.

Comment: Like I said earlier, it seems like a hack. Thanks for accepting it anyway. :)

Comment: I was surprised when it worked, I just wondered... why? haha cheers again!